# android: google map, location is not showing while generating signed keystore

Tags: android

I generated a signed keystore and find MD5 finger print using that i generated a map api key for that MD5 finger print in signup page of MD5...whole process is ok but when I am using that api key, am not getting location in map only blank tiles are showing.

i use in cmd prompt:

```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias saurabhtrivedi -keysto
  "C:\Documents and Settings\Saurabh\.android\ArtPhone_keystorefinal.keystore"
  torepass up78ak5831 -keypass up78ak5831
 up78ak5831, Mar 24, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,
   Certificate fingerprint (MD5): *******************************
```

I am pastred below my manifest file.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.artphone.galleries"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="0.1"
     >
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
     <application android:icon="@drawable/applogo" android:label="@string/app_name"

     >
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
            <activity 
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
             <activity android:name="currentlocmap"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
             <activity android:name="filter"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
             <activity android:name="keywordsearch"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
             <activity android:name="keywordxmlparsing" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
             <activity android:name="Artistspacedetailview" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
             />
             <activity android:name="loadingimage"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
             <activity android:name="keywordpagetabs"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
             <activity android:name="filterpagetabs"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
             />
             <activity android:name="artistspacedetailviewTab"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
             <activity android:name="filtersearchresultparsing"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
             <activity android:name="keywordresulttab"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
             <activity android:name="filterpageresulttab" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
             />
             <activity android:name="artspacedetailShowingNow"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
             <activity android:name="detailviewshowingnowTab" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
             <activity android:name="LatLongparsing"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
             <activity android:name="MyMap"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
             <activity android:name="MainMenu"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
             <activity android:name="spaceinfo"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
              <activity android:name="OpeningToday" 
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
              <activity android:name="Map" 
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
               <activity android:name="Maptab" 
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
               <activity android:name="Loadingimagetab" 
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
              </application>
              <supports-screens
              android:anyDensity = "true"
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true" 
              android:largeScreens="true"
            />
   </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should insert your google maps api key in `com.google.android.maps.MapView` object in your map's activity layout.
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:apiKey="your_api_key"
            android:clickable="true" >

         </com.google.android.maps.MapView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's full step-by-step tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html